# Setting up OmniPascal extension for Visual Studio Code on OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, omnipascal

I'm using Visual Studio Code on OS X El Capitan. I've installed the **OmniPascal** extension in **Visual Studio Code** for coding using **Free Pascal** as the compiler **without** Delphi or lazarus installation.

The installation guide on https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Wosi.omnipascal says I should set `objectpascal.delphiInstallationPath` to the Delphi installation path. I don't know what is this setting for, and I don't have Delphi installed. Since the page also says the extension is for Free Pascal coding too, I wonder that what value works for Free Pascal or no value should be set.

Additionally, about another setup `objectpascal.searchPath`, does the search path means the directory of Pascal units or source files or both?

Comment: I create the needed tag i.e omnipascal. This will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

OmniPascal is now available for Windows, Mac and Linux.

**Original post**

The OmniPascal language service is currently running on Windows only. 
So you only have syntax highlighting and basic code snippets on a Mac. Code completion, finding declarations, outlining and other language related features require a Windows machine for now.

The language service will work on Mac and Linux in the future but there are other important topics to be covered before porting the code to different platforms.

Upvote [this issue](https://bitbucket.org/Wosi/omnipascalissues/issues/6/add-rich-language-support-for-mac-and) to increase the relevance of this topic.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=30507.0) on Lazarus forums FPC is not yet supported, to come in 2016.